# CentOS 6 tftp server default boot menu

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, tftp

**Edit: I figured it out. I just had to set permissions on my files properly which was causing problems (did not see how I missed that). Thanks everybody for the suggesstions.**

I am trying to install a TFTP Server on CentOS 6. The idea is that the machine I install it on is a server and it allows clients to boot over the network to start the boot options listed within my tftp configuration.

I am trying to give the users 4 different options, a local boot, a centos installer/rescue and a memtest. The problem I am having is that I can successfully start a client to boot via network and connect to the boot, but it throws an error saying that no default option was found (this was due to default not being set).

I don't want the menu to default to something, I simply want it to timeout for 30 seconds so that the user can pick an option (they can press F1 for a list of options). It boots to local hard drive after 30 seconds unless they pick another label.

My `/tftpd` directory has a `/images, pxelinux.0, pxelinux.cfg (within this is the default, helpfile, boot.message)`

My default file:

```
default #dont know what to put here
display  boot.message
F1  helpfile
prompt 0
timeout 300
ontimeout local


MENU TITLE Main Menu

LABEL local
    MENU LABEL Boot LOcal
    LOCALBOOT 0

LABEL centinstaller
   MENU LABEL Installer
   APPEND images/initrd.img linux

LABEL centrescue
   MENU LABEL Rescue
   APPEND images/initrd.img linux rescue

LABEL memtest
   MENU LABEL testmem
   KERNEL images/memtest86+-4.10
```

Basically, the user enters in the label to boot that option (be it memtest or local hard drive boot). But this configuration does not actually let me press F1 to show the helpfile nor does it do anything...it actually freezes once the client is booted up along with showing a message default not set. What do I actually set it to so that I can achieve what I want?

I configured everything else (dhcp.d, /etc/xinetd.d/tftp)

Comment: And what do you want to happen _after_ the 30 second timeout?

Comment: After 30 seconds, it just boots to the local (i.e. local hard drive). Thats what the ontimeout local is for (this is what I read anyway)

Comment: Then that is your default.

Comment: Yes but the default simply boots to that option right away. I want to be able to give the user a chance to look at the help menu and boot to a different option

Comment: Do you mean that it's not waiting for either the timeout or any user input if the default is configured?  That would be very strange.. can you clarify exactly what the behavior is in that case?

Comment: Yes, when I set the default to local, it automatically does localboot without waiting for timeout and user input (followed by nothing found because I did not put anything on its local hard drive). Is there a way to stop it from doing this (I thought timeout did this but its not working).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `MENU DEFAULT` setting and you need `menu.c32` to actually display the menu. This is the PXE config I've set up at work (with irrelevant details stripped out, it's actually autogenerated from a django template and a bit more complex):

```
PROMPT 0
DEFAULT menu.c32
MENU TITLE Booking.com PXE environment
MENU AUTOBOOT Booting local in # seconds
TIMEOUT 100

LABEL local
    MENU DEFAULT
    MENU LABEL local
    LOCALBOOT 0x80

LABEL co6-x86_64
    MENU LABEL co6-x86_64
    kernel ...
    append ...

LABEL DiskWipe
    MENU LABEL Disk Wipe/Erase
    KERNEL /menu.c32
    APPEND /dban/isolinux.cfg
```